# AngularJS: Two inputs with separate ngModel, one updating other's value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have two separate input fields, each with their own model, with one of them updating the other's value by default.

```
<form id="registerForm" ng-submit="create(email, username, password)">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{email}}" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">

    <input type="submit" value="register" class="button" ng-show="!loading">
    <input type="submit" value="processing" class="button" disabled ng-show="loading">
</form>
```

The result being that if you type in your email, the username input will be auto populated with it, though username can be changed if specifically typing in to it.

This doesn't work though. Instead, the `ng-model="username"` overrides the value attr, regardless of whatever is set there. So the username input stays empty until explicitly typing in to it.

Is there a way to do this along these lines, or does it require a special directive or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `value`:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
```

Use `$watch` in your controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('email', function(value) {
        $scope.username = value
    });
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJ2t2/)